# How dynamically create ReactJs Router for Links and render a page for each Links?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects(`titleUrl`) contains titles and urls that is coming from an API. I used a custom component called `MenuLink` to create links on the sidebar and the links are populated using `Object.keys(titleUrl).map` method from the `titleUrl` array.

What I'm trying to achieve here is, When I click on each menu items it should redirect to a page created using `pagerender` component which is given as `to={{ pathname: "/pagerender"}` in the example

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { MenuLink } from "../components/MenuLink";

class CreateLinks extends React.Component{
    render(){
        var titleUrl= [
            {"title1":"url1"},
            {"title2":"url2"},
            {"title3":"url3"},
            ...
            ...
        ];
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                { 
                    Object.keys(titleUrl).map((item, i) => (
                        <MenuLink key={item} element={Link} to={{ pathname: "/pagerender"} >{ titleUrl[item].title }</MenuLink>
                    ))
                }   
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default CreateLinks;
```

**Partial Solution so far**

I was able to create the links dynamically.

**Need to achieve**

Dynamically created routes for these links and when we click on these links, url of the same title (from the array of object) should pass as an argument to the `pagerender` and using this argument `pagerender` renders the page

Comment: You need to define which URL corresponds to which component. Then you can create dynamic menu which maps specific title to URL (which should be valid and mapped to specific component using Route).

Comment: hi Zhuber I'm trying here to render the page with only one component without creating multiple components .. The render logic will be selected from the url  argument passed

Comment: Then just define <Route path="/pagerender" component={YourComponent} />.  Or you have different query params for each link and that is your problem?

Comment: Thanks @zhuber will try that and will update here

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array of configs and then map over them:

```
const links = [
  { label: Link1, value: "/link1" },
  { label: Link2, value: "/link2" }
]

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/link1",
    component: Link1
  },
  {
    path: "/link2",
    component: Link2
  }
]

// In render

<Container>
  <Nav>
    {links.map(link => {
      return (
        <MenuLink
          key={link.url}
          element={Link}
          to={{ pathname: link.url }}
        >
          {link.label}>
        </MenuLink>
      );
    })}
  </Nav>
  {routes.map((route) => {
    return (
      <Route
        key={route.path}
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        component={route.component}
      />
    );
  })}
</Container>
```

Comment: inside the return path={route.path} is not working .. here also the links are created but next part is not working